# telerik calendar synchronization with outlook calendar?

Tags: xamarin.forms, outlook, calendar, telerik

there is a way to recover data on an outlook calendar to display them on a telerik calendar in xamarin

I haven't found anything so far

Comment: you're not going to be able to get the data from the Outlook app.  You need to look at were Outlook is getting its data from and then see if there is a way for your app to access that same data source

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.